# Why doesn't a pipe open work under Perl's taint mode?

Tags: perl, taint

My original script is as follows:

```
my $cmd = "dir";
open (H, "$cmd |");
my @result = <H>;
close (H);
print STDERR @result,"\n";
```

This scripts works fine. If I add following line to the script, it fails to work:

```
$ENV{"LD_LIBRARY_PATH"} = "/opt/VRTSsfmh/lib";
$ENV{PATH}="/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin";
delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};
```

What does Perl use when pipe open is called?

Addition of following code fixed the issue:

```
if ($^O =~ /Win32/i) 
{
    $ENV{'SystemRoot'} =~ /([A-Z]:(\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+)+)/;
    my $system32_dir = $1."\\system32";
    $ENV{'PATH'} = $system32_dir;
}
```

Comment: When saying that something "fails to work", it usually helps to describe how it fails in more details.  For example, does it produce an error message, and if so, what is that message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not really related to taint mode. You set

```
$ENV{PATH}="/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin";
```

These directories do not normally exist on a Windows machine. `dir` is a cmd.exe internal command so to be able to execute that, you need to add the directory where it resides to the path.

Now, note that the way you go about doing it contradicts the whole point of setting the path to known definite locations. It is definitely possible for a nefarious user to change this environment variable to point to his dangerous version of `dir`.

The fact that Windows is not necessarily installed in C:\Windows complicates writing a taint-safe script on Windows if you rely on any of the shell builtins.

**EDIT:** Here is a short test program you can use as a baseline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

$ENV{PATH} = join(';', qw(C:\Windows C:\Windows\System32) );
delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};

open my $pipe_h, '-|', 'dir'
    or die "Cannot open pipe to dir: $!";

print while <$pipe_h>;

close $pipe_h
    or die "Cannot close pipe to dir: $!";

__END__

C:\Temp> perl -T v.pl

...

2009/05/25  08:58 AM             3,584 zzz.exe
              64 File(s)     32,125,365 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  39,251,894,272 bytes free
```

Basically, what you need is for the system administrator to hardcode the acceptable path at installation time and for untrusted users not to have write permissions on the script.

Comment: Thanks For your reply, that is the code coming from unix tree. You can ignore that code. even if I just add following lines delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};
my code stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Taint mode is complicated.  You really must read and understand [`perldoc perlsec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html).  Your problem is addressed in the first sentence of the [Cleaning Up Your Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Cleaning-Up-Your-Path) section.